# What I should I replace local host with to run my web application from elsewhere?

Tags: networking, deployment

I'm having a static IP address, say:127.254.x.x
Is it possible to access my web application from some other place by just replacing the local host with my IP???

Also, what will I replace the local host with if Ithe server is on a wifi network.? I.e. The router assigns a different ip to my server(because of dhcp) other than my original static ip. In this case should it be
192.x.x.2:8090
Or
127.254.x.x

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not related to java.

Comment: I've removed the `java` and `jsp` tags. As Bosko says, they're irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having a static IP address, say:127.254.x.x Is it possible to access my web application from some other place by just replacing the local host with my IP???

Yes, provided you configure it correctly.

Normally, you have a broadband modem/router which talks to the outside world, and provides a NAT network range to your devices. So you have an external IP address (the one the modem/router uses to talk to the outside world), and probably several internal IP addresses (for your phone, your laptop, your other laptop, your Kindle, etc.).

So to access a web server on your internal network from the outside world, you have to do two things:

1. Configure your modem/router to "forward" traffic it receives on the desired port (port 80 for HTTP) to the server on your network. How you do this depends on your modem/router. Look for "port forwarding."
2. When trying to access the app from the outside world, use your external, not internal, IP address.

So for instance, if your external IP address is 222.111.222.12, and the IP address of the machine you're using as your web server is 127.154.0.23, then you tell your modem/router that whatever traffic it receives on port 80 it should forward to 127.154.0.23 (this configuration may be by IP address, or may be by the MAC address of the network card in your web server machine; it depends on the modem/router). Then to view your app from outside your network, you go to `http://222.111.222.12` (or whatever name you assign that IP address to in DNS).